# HTML Form input into Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to enter a single name into a html Text form. Each time I press submit

it will store that value into a javascript array.  Currently, I  am able to get
the first value I submit into the array but not the subsequent values. Hope I am
being clear enough, Any help would be great.

Here is my JavaScript

```js
function getListOfNames() {
 "use strict";

  //Declare variables
  var form;
  var getNameValue;
  var myArray = [];
  var output;

  //Assign values 
  output = document.getElementById("myTable");
  form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  getNameValue = form.getNameValue.value;

  //Each time form is submited put the new value into array

  myArray.push(getNameValue);

  //output the results 

  output.innerHTML = myArray;
}

function project5Part2() {
  "use strict";

  // Your code goes in here.

   getListOfNames();

  return false;

}



Here is my HTML

<form  id="myForm" action="#"  onsubmit=" return project5Part2();" > 
  <label for="firstName">Enter Name</label> 
  <input type="text" id="enteredName" name="getNameValue"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter Name" />
  <input type="reset"  value="Clear form - DO NOT SEND" />
</form>
```

Comment: Aside from the errors in your code, when you submit your form the page is going to post so your array will be re-initialized as an empty array

Comment: What is the html for your output? With that we can make your code runnable....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Html Form Information in to an JS Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570492/storing-html-form-information-in-to-an-js-array)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onsubmit from the form.
change the `input type="submit"` into a regular button and use the onclick to execute JavaScript.

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" > 
      <label for="firstName">Enter Name</label> 
      <input type="text" id="enteredName" name="getNameValue"/>
      <button type="button" onclick="project5Part2();">Enter Name</button>
      <input type="reset"  value="Clear form - DO NOT SEND" />
    </form>
```

Create or use a global array (cannot be enclosed in the method if you want to persist)

When the button is clicked, checked the value of the textbox and if not empty, add the value to the array.

```
var myArray = new Array();
    function project5Part2() {
        var name = document.getElementById('enteredName').value;
        if (!(typeof name === 'undefined') && name!=null && name.trim()!='') {  
            myArray.push(name);
        }
        console.log(myArray);
        document.getElementById('enteredName').value = '';
    }
```

Will log the contents of the array each time the button is clicked. 
For example: `["albert", "manny", "susan"]`

The textbox value is being cleared each time the name is added.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I appreciate it . You have been very helpful.